# Algorithm for distribute matrix in pikachu game

Tags: c++, algorithm, matrix, game-engine

I think almost everyone knows about game Pikachu

[image]

I am learning about algorithm course, and I stuck in creating a matrix NxM which has a "level" in this matrix(like Pikachu game).

Level is the combine of the number of difference Pikachu types and the number of pair cards which we can match in only one step from the beginning. Which mean that the high level will have more Pikachu types and less number pair cards in the begining

Is it possible to creating a matrix like that? or Pikachu game just creates randomly

Comment: Pikachu? didnt you mean to say Pokemon? and i think most of us don't know this game... is it like Candy Crush where you have yo make a row or col of 3 of the same kind? (for example in this picture: replace [row 2, col 2] with [row 2, col 1])

Comment: @yd1, No, the rule is to find two Pokemon cards which the route between them can not exceed more than two times change direction.

This is a example
http://hoigame.net/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/game-pikachu-moi.jpg

Comment: any chance you mean Mah Jong? http://www.mahjongdragon.com/art/mahjongconnect_inst_con.jpg

Comment: Nope, I have no idea what a Pikachu game is and you've shown no attempt to code a solution or even to sufficiently define the problem, therefore I'm voting to close this question as unclear.